# Covert JSON Array file into graph using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, request

**I am grabbing a JSON file from a server which has the following format:**

```
[{"target": "carbon.agents.graphite01TimeTemp",
  "datapoints": 
    [  
       [0.00034302131648684774, 1395792060],
       [0.00041960148485072106, 1395792120],
       [0.00035245191970241269, 1395792180], 
       [0.00032920416076246247, 1395792240],
       ...
       [0.00034535436076246232, 1395792546]
    ]
}]
```

I am grabbing it using a node.js request using [this](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library.

**This is my full code:**

```
var request = require('request');
request('###grabthejsondataurl###', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var returnval= JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(body);
        config.temp = returnval.datapoints;
        console.log(config.temp);
        job_callback(null, config);
    } 
})
```

The `console.log(body)` print out the JSON I displayed above.

But the `console.log(config.temp)` print out `undefined`.

Anybody understand why this is happening???

**Extra Information:**

The values on the left (0.0003342 etc) are temperatures and the values on the right (1395 etc) are the times.

The plan is to get all this data into an array in JavaScript then convert it into a graph.

Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data object is contained within an array. You can access it with: `returnval[0].datapoints`.

Try:

```
var request = require('request');
request('###grabthejsondataurl###', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var returnval= JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(body);
        config.temp = returnval[0].datapoints;
        console.log(config.temp);
        job_callback(null, config);
    } 
})
```

Comment: You're welcome. From time to time, it happens to all of us :)

Comment: It is returning `[  
       [0.00034302131648684774, 1395792060],
       [0.00041960148485072106, 1395792120],
       [0.00035245191970241269, 1395792180], 
       [0.00032920416076246247, 1395792240],
       ...
       [0.00034535436076246232, 1395792546]
    ]` now, what do you think the best way to convert this into 2 arrays is? one with the temp and the other with the time?

Comment: var temp = config.temp.map(function(a){return a[0]});

Comment: You can also implement `pluck` for such operations: `function (obj, key){return obj.map(function(a){return a[key];})}`. Then `var temp = pluck(config.temp, 0);`. `Pluck`, among other useful functions, is included in underscore.js.